# How to change open files (ulimit -n) permanently for normal user in Debian Stretch?

Tags: debian, ulimit

I wanna change system open files setting permanently, but it doesn't work.

My login user is a normal user, not `root`. I did the following operation:

**file** `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
$ grep 'fs.file-max' /etc/sysctl.conf
fs.file-max = 800000
```

**file** `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
$ grep nofile /etc/security/limits.conf
#        - nofile - max number of open files
* soft nofile 655360
* hard nofile 655360
```

*Setting `/etc/security/limits.conf` is work on CentOS/OpenSUSE, but it not works in Debian.*

**Add**

```
session    required   pam_limits.so
```

into file `/etc/pam.d/common-session{,-noninteractive}`, file `/etc/pam.d/login` already has it. Absolute path is

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_limits.so
```

After **reboot**, execute `ulimit -n`, the output is still the default value **1024**.

```
$ ulimit -n
1024
```

What should I do to take it effect?

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://serverfault.com/questions/610130/how-to-set-ulimit-value-permanently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem in Debian. 
It's a problem in systemd + gnome.
systemd chosen not read or use limits.conf, gdm chosen let systemd set it's limit.
ssh sudo su tty will use `/etc/seecurity/limits.conf` as normal.
See this bug [systmd --user does not load limits from /etc/security/limits.d/](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1364332)  in Fedora. In the discussion this solution work for me.

Create file `/etc/systemd/system/user@1000.service.d/limit.conf`, replace *1000* as your userId, set limit in this file as in systemd service:

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=655360
```

Comment: For Oracle Linux 8.0 it was a file called /etc/systemd/system/user@1000.service.d/limits.conf, also i had to reboot before so the change is visible with ulimit -a